# iMac won't recognise .MTS videos on my hard drive, how can I play them?

Tags: imac, video, encoding

We just purchased an iMac yesterday to view our travel videos. The thing is, all the videos we have stored on our external Hard Drive are in the .MTS file format (AVCHD). The thing is, the Mac or QuickTime won't recognize them. Are there any good / free file converters so we can convert the video files to .MOV as that seems to be the common file format for Macs.

I read on-line that you can fool your computer into thinking that it is reading the video file straight from the Camcorder instead of from an external Hard Drive but you have to reorganize the storage or hierarchy of the videos. Apparently this can take up a lot of memory though - maybe up to 10 times the size of the original video file size? Is it a viable solution?

What's the best / most straight-forward / preferably free way to get the videos into a usable format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [VideoLan](http://www.videolan.org/index.html). It is free and should handle most kinds of video formats.

The method for recognising AVCHD format is with regard to Apple Video applications, and not QuickTime. Those applications have the reader for that format. But you're only interested in viewing them so I suggested VideoLan.

Also there is a QuickTime plugin which recognises many formats, but I have never tried it with AVCHD or MTS formats. It is called [Perian](http://perian.org). Please note that it is no longer supported in the form of updates but it is still offered on the official site.

Answer (score 1):

### QuickTime Player

QuickTime Player supports AVCHD files. The clips need to be converted first and must be mounted via a camera or external device. See [OS X Mountain Lion: About AVCHD files and QuickTime Player](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5409) for the specific details.

### Watch with VLC

As others have suggested, [VideoLAN Client](http://www.videolan.org/index.html) (VLC) is capable of watching your MTS files without needing conversion.

### Convert with Handbrake

[Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr) is an open source tool that can transcode video, including [MTS to MPEG4](http://allmybrain.com/2010/01/05/handbrake-can-convert-mts-files-for-mac/). As Scott Earle suggests, it provides a graphical interface for the underlying `ffmpeg` tool that performs the conversion.

### Convert with `ffmpeg`

If you want to use your MTS files in iMovie or other tools, consider converting them to MPEG4 first.

The open source tool [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org) can convert AVCHD/MTS files to a wide range of formats.

The simplest way of installing `ffmpeg` onto your computer is through the [homebrew project](http://brew.sh). To install `brew`, launch **Terminal.app** and issue the command:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

With `brew` successfully installed, you can now install `ffmpeg`:

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

There are numerous tutorials for converting video formats with `ffmpeg`. A couple are linked below.

- [Convert an AVCHD / MTS file to MP4 using ffmpeg](http://pvdm.xs4all.nl/wiki/index.php/Convert_an_AVCHD_/_MTS_file_to_MP4_using_ffmpeg)
- [FFmpeg Tutorial: Convert MTS/M2TS(AVCHD) to AVI](http://floss.zoomquiet.io/data/20100202095215/index.html)

The final command will approximate:

```
ffmpeg -i 00031.MTS -b:v 4000k 00031.MP4
```

Comment: What about Handbrake? Much nicer than diving into Terminal

Comment: Thanks Scott. I have updated the answer to include Handbrake. I did not know it too could convert from MTS.

Comment: I think Handbrake is itself a wrapper for ffmpeg, among other things :)

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of OS X (I think 10.9+) now support the AVCHD container. But if you extract just the .MTS files on their own it won't know what to do with them (which is a bit of a cop-out, because obviously apps like VLC can play them!).

If you just have MTS files, you can actually re-build an AVCHD container for them using Panasonic's [AVCCam Restorer](https://eww.pass.panasonic.co.jp/pro-av/support/content/download/EN/restorer.html) utility (both Mac & Windows).

This was a huge help for me, because I backed up only the MTS files for heaps of videos, because I didn't really understand the AVCHD container. I've been able to go back and re-make AVCHD containers for them, and then easily convert them out of that container into something simpler to manage (i.e. individual clips), without (lossy) transcoding.

Comment: Seems the BDMV files inside AVCHD can be opened with Quicktime player (Big Sur 11.6.7, FinalCut installed)

Answer (score 0):

Try the free [AVCHD to MOV Lite](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/free-avchd-to-mov/id675103877?mt=12) on the App Store to convert it to MOV format, and then import to Photos. This will `remux` the video (convert it without reprocessing/converting the audio or video) losslessly.

(Hat tip to [How can I convert .MTS file (AVCHD) to .mp4 by ffmpeg without re-encoding H264 video stream?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12156/how-can-i-convert-mts-file-avchd-to-mp4-by-ffmpeg-without-re-encoding-h264-v?newreg=6b144c4e8b8f4b55a4725a969f5e3167)
).